# Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now when i run in loop

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

When i put stoe procedure inside for loop i am getting error as above.

i am using phpmyadmin

Can anyone plz help me

```
$sum=0;

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $overall_sat=mysql_query("call daily_sales('HO Bangalore','2013-07-01','2013-07-06')");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($overall_sat)){?>
        <td><?php echo $row['sat'];
        $sum=$sum+$row['sat'];?></td>
    <?}
 }
 if(!$overall_sat){
    echo mysql_error();
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: The if should be before your while loop: `if( ! $overall_sat) { mysql_error(); } else { while() { // Do stuff } }`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your stored procedure returns multiple result sets. A new query can only be issued on a connection after *all* pending results have been fetched. 
To process procedure call results you need to use `mysqli_next_result()` / `mysqli_more_results()`. See [example](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query).

Stop using mysql, it's outdated.

Comment: i am using mysql_fetch_array.. is the prob with this?

Comment: m not getting u .can u be more specific as were to use mysqli_next_result() in my query