# how to call stored procedure inside for loop

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

i have php code as folloes where i call store procedure inside for loop.But when i execute m getting eror "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now "
but if i remove for loop m getting correct result

```
<?php 
$sum=0;
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $overall_sat=mysql_query("call daily_sales('HO Bangalore','2013-07-01','2013-07-30')");

        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($overall_sat)){ echo "<pre>"; print_r($row);?>
            <td><?php echo $row['0'];
            $sum=$sum+$row['sat'];?></td>
        <?}
}
if(!$overall_sat){
    echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible(!) duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012881/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now-when-i-run-in-loop

Answer (score 0):

your connection is going lost so before calling stored procedure first close the connection and again create connectivity with database

```
<?php 
$sum=0;
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    mysql_close();          // close connection
   // create connectivity

    $overall_sat=mysql_query("call daily_sales('HO Bangalore','2013-07-01','2013-07-30')");

        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($overall_sat)){ echo "<pre>"; print_r($row);?>
            <td><?php echo $row['0'];
            $sum=$sum+$row['sat'];?></td>
        <?}
}
if(!$overall_sat){
    echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```